# Google Chrome Linux with Activity of Unknown Device

Tags: network, malware, web-browser, access-control, ip

I've recently noticed a strange comportment on my **Google Chrome Browser** with **GMail**, **where suddenly appeared a connected *Unknown Device***, **with a double connection and with the same IP than mine**, **looking at the GMail history Details of accesses**, and I don't know where is the origin of the problem.

**Illustration of the problem** (**Portuguese language location**)**:**

[image: Unknown Device connected with same IP]

**I've already deleted the Profile**, **following the below advice teached in the *Ask Ubuntu* Section**:

**https://askubuntu.com/questions/391858/clearing-all-private-user-data-from-chrome-from-the-command-line**

*( ***Clearing all private user data from Chrome from the command line - Ask Ubuntu*** )

*For the default Chrome configuration, run*

```
 rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/
```

*and*

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/google-chrome
```

, and the strange described problem doesn't gone yet until todays.

This below Topic, also doesn't help to resolve or remedy the problem:

**<https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/105037/remove-access-for-unknown-devices-in-account-activity>**

*( ***security - Remove access for unknown devices in account activity - Web Applications Stack Exchange*** )

. Maybe it's a **viruse**/**malware** on my **Debian**? I'll try to scan my computer, also verifying the **Debian 7 Partition** with ***ESET SysRescue***:

**<https://www.eset.com/int/support/sysrescue/>**

, to know if I'll discover some infection, some trace of hidden prague on my system. I think that this symptom is uncommon and I suspect an infection, and it's the first time that I see this behavior on Linux.

Could someone here help me to investigate the problem? This might not be malware related, only Network issues on a last valid hypothesis. Only rests for me to let unoccupied an USB Flash Drive to make a Bootable AV USB Key for scan my computer, including the Bootable AVs as **Kaspersky Rescue Disk** or the **ESET SysRescue *Linux-based* Security Distributions** (the best Vaccines encountered on the market, according to all my searches).

**Obs.:** Maybe this is a prank of my older brother, accessing the Debian partition with Ubuntu and infecting it with a **virus** / **malware**. Or is it fruit of a infection of a possibly hidden extension on the latest 32-bit version of Google Chrome for Linux (**.deb package**), that was acquired when I was browsing on some harmful websites? I've not managed to encounter a guide with steps, and with a list of probable related causes for resolve the case.

Waiting a return as soon as possible.

Thanks.

**@lhvf**.

Comment: Debian 7 is out of support, and has been so for since May 2018. You should consider upgrading to at least 8.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean that the unknown device has your same **home IP address** -- so, not 192.168.x.y but something belonging, say, to Telecom Brasil.

If this is the case, the problem lies not in your Chrome browser or desktop Debian distribution, but in your home or nearby. Something is accessing your GMail account from your wireless Access Point, which implies it knows the access codes for both.

**The most likely explanation is that you have GMail on your WiFi-connected smartphone also.**

Or you could have some "smart" device somewhere - an Android TV maybe - that's synchronized with your Google account.

Otherwise, it's someone else's device. This is, of course, *potentially* **very bad**. Try changing the passwords on both the account and the access point, using two different, robust, non-guessable passwords, ensure the access point is not vulnerable to some exploits (just google "BrandOfYourDevice exploit" or "BrandOfYourDevice security vulnerability"), it is not accessible from the outside, and is configured for WPA2 security.

Comment: I've inspected the issue, and discovered that it only occurs when I'm using a vulnerable Router, shared with my brother in Wi-Fi, which is Model: "TRENDnet TEW-731BR v3.0R". This Router, according to a Report: <https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-12268/product_id-40538/year-2017/opec-1/Trendnet-Tew-731br-Firmware.html>, has a vulnerability of code execution. Since September 2018, my GMail has been alerted about an unauthorized access (not legitim), and since then, I've not changed my password. Now, if not using this Router or this account, the issue doesn't occurs.

Comment: I'll Update the Firmware of the mentioned TRENDNet Router, to avoid such described vulnerability: (https://drivers.softpedia.com/get/Router-Switch-Access-Point/TRENDnet/TRENDnet-TEW-731BR-v3-0R-Router-Firmware-1-00-02.shtml).

Comment: Forget my statement about get a fix of the security issue by updating the Firmware of the TRENDNet:There's a main Router in the upstair level, and down is the TRENDNet one. By utilize the Call/internet main signal Router, the IP duplication entry remain the same as mine. Removing a fake IP connection, make the duplication increase, also on the first receiving Internet Provider Router, and not only on TRENDNet, as thought. All connections are compromised. My father is more than 60-days without change the Admin./Wi-Fi password. The Two-steps authentication seems to be the workaround encountered.

Comment: And as I use Chrome with Linux on the Internet, the issue doesn't mean to occur only in Linux or Chrome: seems that the issue is cleary residing in all Routers and someone is burlating the security, Security Protocols and SSL (HTTPS (?)), and coming from a nearby Internet connection, and I can state that all my Home is affected, without any differing, and testing how much it affected it happens when I use a clean Live Linux Distribution. It seems to be an issue of malware resident on the all Routers, from a coaxial cable of pole on the street, I don't asked help from ISP, my father ignores it.